# How to get methods in a type

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

Given: System.Type instance.

The aim is to get the newly-introduced methods (i don't know the right word) in the type, which are
- not inherited
- not overridden

I want to use .NET Reflection and I tried the `Type.GetMethods()` method. But, it returned even inherited and overridden ones.

I thought of filtering after getting all the methods. And I looked at the properties/methods exposed by `MethodInfo` class. I could not figure how to get what I wanted.

For instance: I have a class, 
`class A { void Foo() { } }`

When I invoke `typeof(A).GetMethods()` , I get `Foo` along with the methods in `System.Object`: `Equals`, `ToString`, `GetType` and `GetHashCode`. I want to filter it down to only `Foo`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Inherited and overridden methods belong to the type. Why would you expect them to not be listed? Can you please explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to generate a report saying that these methods have been newly added to the library/product. And I do not want to list inherited/overridden methods because of the business requirement. They have to be reported as part of their defining type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`GetMethods` has an overload that lets you specify [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx). E.g. so if you need to get all declared, public, instance methods you need to pass the corresponding flags.

```
var declaredPublicInstanceMethods = 
    typeof(A).GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked for the most part. Overridden methods still show up.

Comment: Well, if A overrides a method that method is part of the declarations of the type so why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this was what you want

```
var methods = typeof(MyType).GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Comment: Did not work. For some reason, the DeclaredOnly flag alone is not sufficient. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
typeof(Foo).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the returned MethodInfo collection by DeclaringType:

```
var methods = typeof(A).GetMethods().Where(mi => mi.DeclaringType== typeof(A));
```